# Не выводит первую запись из БД

Tags: php

Подскажите в чем проблема пытаюсь вывести данные из таблицы в бд,но вывод начинается со второй записи,в чем проблема?

```
  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","apollon","quaresma89");
    $db = mysql_select_db("chat",$connect);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo $result['message'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $result['message'];
}
```

Что делает первый $result = `mysql_fetch_array`($query);? Правильно, получает первую запись. А вы ее выводите? Нет, потому она и не выводится, уберите ее - тогда будут выводиться все записи, т.е.:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages");

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $result['message'];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,невнимательный!